# Sql 2012 - Get data within varchar column

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a column in a table that contains data that looks like this:

**Fusion 2-4 L Jt w Autol Sub, Post Appr P Col, Open [0SG1071],Release Lumbar Nerve, Open Approach [01NB0ZZ],Excision of Right Pelvic Bone, Open Approach [0QB20ZZ],Supplement Spinal Meninges with Nonaut Sub, Open Approach [00UT0KZ]**

I am tasked with getting the data within the brackets of that string and presenting them as either individual records or as one record containing all the values (in which they appear in the string) as a CSV.

In this case, the CSV extract would be

**0SG1071,01NB0ZZ,0QB20ZZ,00UT0KZ**

Any ideas?

the only thing I have been able to do is determine that there are 4 occurrence of a '[' character using this:

```
  select * from (SELECT (LEN([FullPX]) - LEN(REPLACE([FullPX], '[', '')))/LEN('[') as NumOfOccurrence, [FullPX] FROM [Import].[dbo].[_TMC_TEMP]) i1 where i1.NumOfOccurrence > 0
```

Comment: SQL Server 2012 doesn't support regular-expressions (excepting via SQL-CLR) so you'll need to do this in application-code.

Comment: I'm sure you are aware that SQL Server 2012 is now a year out of support...

Comment: Yes, I am aware.  Still waiting on approval from management to make the move...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to generate the comma-delimited values is to replace the delimiters with  XML opening/closing tags and use XML methods to extract the values. Furthermore `FOR XML` can be used for aggregate string concatenation in old unsupported SQL Server versions where `STRING_AGG` is not available.

Below is an example that also replaces an invalid XML character (ampersand)  with entity reference to facilitate XML parsing. This can be extended for other characters in your data that need to be escaped.

```
DECLARE @example TABLE(ID int, UnstructuredData varchar(MAX));
INSERT INTO @example VALUES(1, 'Fusion 2-4 L Jt w Autol Sub, Post Appr P Col, Open [0SG1071],Release Lumbar Nerve, Open Approach [01NB0ZZ],Excision of Right Pelvic Bone, Open Approach [0QB20ZZ],Supplement Spinal Meninges with Nonaut Sub, Open Approach [00UT0KZ]');
INSERT INTO @example VALUES(2, 'Data with invalid XML characters such as an ampersand (&) must be escaped with entity references [ABCDEFGH]');

SELECT 
    ID
    , STUFF(CAST(
        (SELECT ',' + xml_node.value('.', 'varchar(10)')
         FROM (
            SELECT CAST('<data>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(UnstructuredData, '&', '&amp;'), '[', '<value>'), ']', '</value>') + '</data>' AS xml) AS UnstructuredDataXml
        ) AS column_data
        CROSS APPLY UnstructuredDataXml.nodes('//value') AS xml_nodes(xml_node)
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ) AS varchar(MAX)),1,1,'') AS csv_data
FROM @example;
```

Results:

| ID | csv_data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0SG1071,01NB0ZZ,0QB20ZZ,00UT0KZ |
| 2 | ABCDEFGH |

Comment: _"One way to generate the comma-delimited values is to replace the delimiters with XML opening/closing tags and use XML methods to extract the values."_ - That idea came out of leftfield for me, so +1 for originality... even if the result is horrifying :3

Comment: @Dai, this isn't a new technique but I couldn't easily find an existing answer that combined it with aggregate string concatenation.

Comment: This works perfectly for what I was after.  Thank you so much.